# Performing operations needed for sharing only after share button has been clicked

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I use a [`ShareActionProvider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ShareActionProvider) to share images generated by my app.

The thing is: I write a temporary image file to disk for the sole purpose of sharing - the shared image is a composition of multiple bitmaps on the screen, let's say in my own function `createComposition(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2)`. Right now, I run `createComposition(b1, b2)` every time that content changes, so that any possible share will result in a correct image being shared, but this leads to a lot of cpu cycles (and disk writes) wasted, because most content changes won't result in a share.

So I would rather create this temporary file *after* the user has clicked the share button, so that I don't have to generate a potentially useless image on disk every time the on-screen content changes. Question: how do I get there? Is there a listener for the `ShareActionProvider`? `onOptionsItemSelected` doesn't go off, anyway.

Do I need to extend `ShareActionProvider`, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OnShareTargetSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener.html) Appears to be what you are looking for.